# How can I run a Python script on a server at a given time on all the days?

Tags: python, scripting, automation, server, operating-system

I can keep a Python script running all the time with a specific delay time but that looks too silly as it keeps on using the system that too being idle so whats the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `cron`. On command line it's `crontab -e` to open a vim editor where you can schedule things to run. Here's the [documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto). So to run a script every minute ever with cron you would add this line to your crontab:

```
* * * * * python <path to>/script.py
```

First * is every minute, but could eg be a number between 0 and 59 to run once an hour, second * codes for hour of day, third is day of month and so on.